# Updating MySQL with JSON object using For Each -- Checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, checkbox

I am attempting to update the table (auth_users) with these checkbox values using QueryBuilder and the following code but it is not working for the checkboxes on my form.

I think its not working maybe because $key,"'".$value."'" does not equal the DB field name and the correct value, but actually equals "name":"checked" instead of "mb":"1"

I may be wrong on this.  I basically and trying to figure out how to loop through this JSON object and update the values in a row for a particular $id.  If the box is checked it would update "1" if not then it would update "0".

I have 26 checkbox values to update for each record in the DB.
DB Table Structure
uName,uFname,uLName,uSecurityLevel,mb,mc,ms,mi,ml,mp,mo,mst,si,ei,ai,ci,ali,hli .... etc ...  (See data in JSON object below)

JQUERY FUNCTION:

```
function getCheckBoxRights()
  {
   var cbr = new Array();
   $(".rchk").each(function(i,e)
     {
     // loop through each checkbox and discover if it is checked,
     // and if so value = 1 else value = 0
     if($(e)[0].checked) cbr.push({"name":$(e).attr('name'),"checked":"1"});
     else cbr.push({"name":$(e).attr('name'),"checked":"0"});
     });
  console.log(cbr);
  return JSON.stringify(cbr);
  }
```

This returns the following JSON object for the status of the checkboxes:

```
[{"name":"ai","checked":"1"},{"name":"hi","checked":"1"},
{"name":"hhi","checked":"1"},{"name":"pii","checked":"1"},
{"name":"li","checked":"1"},{"name":"gi","checked":"1"},
{"name":"si","checked":"1"},{"name":"ci","checked":"1"},
{"name":"ei","checked":"1"},{"name":"voi","checked":"0"},
{"name":"hli","checked":"1"},{"name":"gli","checked":"1"},
{"name":"sli","checked":"1"},{"name":"usli","checked":"1"},
{"name":"ali","checked":"1"},{"name":"cli","checked":"1"},
{"name":"mb","checked":"1"},{"name":"mc","checked":"0"},
{"name":"md","checked":"0"},{"name":"mi","checked":"1"},
{"name":"ml","checked":"0"},{"name":"mp","checked":"0"},
{"name":"mo","checked":"0"},{"name":"ms","checked":"0"},
{"name":"mst","checked":"0"},{"name":"mu","checked":"0"}]
```

AJAX CALL:

```
$.ajax(
  {
   dataType:'JSON',
   type:'POST',
   cache:false,
   url:'dump.php',
   data:'myaction=updatec&t=auth_users&id='+data.uID+'&jsonc='+getCheckBoxRights()
  });

  var jsonc = getCheckBoxRights();
  console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!');
  console.log('CheckBox JSON Object:'+jsonc);
  console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!');
  console.log('ID of record to update: '+data.uID);
```

DUMP.PHP FILE:

```
case "updatec":
  {
  if(!isset($id)) break;
  $jsonc = urldecode($jsonc);
  $jsonc = stripslashes($jsonc);
  updatec($jsonc,$t,$id);
  break;
  }

function updatec($jsonc,$table,$id)
  {
  $tables = array("auth_users");
  if(!in_array($table,$tables)) return false;
  $updateQuery = new UpdateQuery($table);
  $datac = json_decode($jsonc);
    foreach($datac as $key=>$value)
    {
    $updateQuery->addItem($key,"'".$value."'");
    }
    $updateQuery->addCondition("uID",$id);
    $query = $updateQuery->generateQuery();
    $bool = TableFunctions::executeQuery($query); 
    $p = new stdClass();
    $p->ok = 0;
    $p->uID = $id; // the id of the record we updated
    if($bool) $p->ok = 1;
    echo json_encode($p);
  }
```

**I was thinking maybe I could decode the data like this maybe and perform the update then?**

```
$updatechk = json_decode($jsonc, true);
foreach($updatechk['name'] as $key => $updatechk['checked'] as $value)
{
  if($value) 
  {
  //how to use json array to insert data in Database
  mysql_query("UPDATE auth_users SET ".$key." = '".$value."' WHERE uID = '". $id ."'");
  }
}
```

**Does this look like the correct way to do this?  I am just a little lost trying to make this happen any assistance would be great.**

Checkbox HTML (per request)

```
<div id="inventoryRights" style="display:none;float:right;width:43.3%;"><strong><u>Inventory Rights</u></strong><p>
<input type="checkbox" id="ai" name="ai" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="ai"> Active&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="hi" name="hi" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="hi"> Hold&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="hhi" name="hhi" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="hhi"> Hold Indefinately&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="pii" id="pii" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="pii"> Pending&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="li" name="li" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="li"> Link<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="gi" name="gi" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="gi"> Greeny&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="si" id="si" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="si"> Sold&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="ci" name="ci" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="ci"> Cancelled&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="ei" name="ei" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="ei"> Edit&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="voi" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="voi"> View Only<p>
<strong><u>Default Views</u></strong><p>
<input type="checkbox" name="hli" id="hli" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="hli"> Hold List&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="gli" id="gli" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="gli"> Greeny List&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="sli" name="sli" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="sli"> Sold List&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="usli" name="usli" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="usli"> Unsold List<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="ali" id="ali" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="ali"> Archived List&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="cli" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" id="cli" data-prop="cli"> Cancelled List</div>

<div id="allowableRights" style="display:none;padding:5px;width:55%;">&nbsp;<strong><u>System Rights</u></strong><p>
<input type="checkbox" id="mb" name="mb" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="mb"> Manage Bedrooms&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="mc" name="mc" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="mc"> Manage Companies&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="md" data-table="auth_users" id="md" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="md"> Manage Descriptions&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="mi" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" id="mi" data-prop="mi"> Manage Inventory<p>
<input type="checkbox" id="ml" name="ml" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="ml"> Manage Locations&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="mp" name="mp" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="mp"> Manage Properties&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="mo" id="mo" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="mo"> Manage Owners<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="ms" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" id="ms" data-prop="ms"> Manage Sleeps&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="mst" name="mst" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="mst"> Manage States&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" id="mu" name="mu" data-table="auth_users" class="rchk json-input" data-prop="mu"> Manage Users</div>
```

Here is what it looks like when an admin selected to manage a user (all data is pulled from DB and populates fields and checkboxes.)
[image: Manage User]

Comment: Woh, not a single indentation...? :-/

Comment: Since I am attempting to urldecode the $jsonc in the data URL, maybe I need to use? return encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(cbr));  Sorry about the indents or lack there of.

Comment: Added indentation... Sorry.

Comment: Can I see your HTML pls :)

Comment: Currently the way this works, is a user clicks "manage" for a particular user.  The form slides up with all the data for that user already in the form fields (which works perfectly.)  Its just when I goto change a check box value and update the record, it isnt looping through the respective changes and updating the DB.  It is updating the "text" field values and textarea, but just not the checkboxes, to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fingured it out. =)  Below shows the working code.  The problem was 2 part.  One I was only looping through the JSON object once, and two the formation of the JSON object was incorrect.

**Here is the working code:**
in DUMP.PHP

```
case "updatec":
{
 if(!isset($id)) break;
 updatec($jsonc,$table,$id)
 break;
}

 function updatec($jsonc,$table,$id)
 {
 $updateQuery = new UpdateQuery($table);
 $datac = json_decode($jsonc,true);
    foreach ($datac as $key => $jsons) {
      foreach($jsons as $key => $value) {
      $updateQuery->addItem($key,"'".$value."'");
      }
    }
 }
```

And in the FUNCTION Rewrite:

```
function getCheckBoxRights()
{
var cbr = new Array();
$(".rchk").each(function(i,e)
   {
 //get type and info, then setup an object to push onto the array
   if($(e)[0].checked)
      {
      var datatype = $(e).attr('name'),
      info = "1",
      obj  = {};
      obj[datatype] = info;
      cbr.push(obj);
      }
      else
      {
      var datatype = $(e).attr('name'),
      info = "0",
      obj  = {};
      obj[datatype] = info;
      cbr.push(obj);
      }
   });
 console.log(cbr);
 return JSON.stringify(cbr);
}
```

Thanks for at least responding and allowing me to go back through all the code again and try to create a new way to do this.  Jquery/AJAX can be challenging but learning is great!